# Mapping вложеных объектов в SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Есть класс в котором содержаться два поля типа `String`, и списки объектов.

Сам контакт я могу добавить таким способом:

```
public boolean insertContact(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME, name);

    db.insert("contacts_caling", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

А каким образом можно добавить контакт вместе со вложенным объектом или списком, если они связаны по `COLUMN_CONTACT_ID`.
Т.е. для того что бы добавить контакт со всем содержимым нужно сначала добавить его самого, потом повторно сделать запрос и узнать 
какой у него `_id`, после чего уже добавлять вложенные объекты устанавливая им уже известное поле `COLUMN_CONTACT_ID`, либо это можно делать как то одним запросом?

Вот пример таблици Контакт и к примеру таблици Email

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
    private String id;
    private String displayName;
    private ArrayList<Phone> phone;
    private ArrayList<Email> email;
    private ArrayList<String> notes;
    private ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    private ArrayList<IM> imAddresses;
    private Organization organization;
}
```

**TableContact.java**

```
public class ContactTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "contacts";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";


    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
            + TABLE_CONTACT
            + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " text"
            + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion) {
        Log.w(ContactCalingTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

**TableContactEmail.java**

```
public class EmailTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT_CALING_EMAIL = "contact_email";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_ID = "contact_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";



    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
                    + TABLE_CONTACT_EMAIL
                    + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_CONTACT_ID + " integer, "
                    + COLUMN_ADDRESS + " text, "
                    + COLUMN_TYPE + " text"
                    + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion) {
        Log.w(ContactCalingTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_EMAIL);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

**Доп. вопрос:** нужно ли в данном случае делать `COLUMN_CONTACT_ID` как `foreign key`, или не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreign key` появились только с Android 2.2, и эту фичу надо специально включать, насколько я помню. Поэтому я бы сказал что не нужно вам это.

Ответ на основной вопрос: да, надо делать доп. запрос. `db.insert(...)` вернет `ROWID` по которому получаете ваш `primary key` и используете его для вставки в таблицу мейлов.